# Apache settings and PHP headers (download a csv)

Tags: php, apache, csv, header

I am trying to create a .csv report using PHP headers. The headers I am using are here:

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=certificates.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Originally, the code outputted a .xls file, but it was essentially html output. I did not write this original code so all I did was change the output and the second header above. For some reason, this works fine on my staging server but not the production server. The permissions are the same so I was thinking maybe it had something to with the Apache settings. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be Content-type: text/csv ? Could you please explain what is not working?

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work" means exactly? What happens?

Comment: When I try to open the file in a browser, it says it cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is as follows:

add an 'AddType' line as follows to your .htaccess file or your main server config file in the appropriate place (I can't say exactly where as I don't know what distro your Apache is running on)

```
AddType application/octet-stream csv
```

Then use the following snippet of PHP to deliver your file

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.csv');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile("name and path of CSV file you wish to send");
```

Alternatively use PHP to send the lines of CSV rather than using ReadFile to generate it from disk.  Make sure you use the correct line terminator too '\n' on the end of each line should do the job for for Internet Explorer targets you may need '\r\n'

You will also want to send a

```
header("Content-Length: xxxx");
```

where the 'xxxx' above should be replaced with the size of your CSV content, if you don't provide a content length, then there's a chance the server won't know when to close the connection and signal that the download is complete (In practice a very rare occurrence but it can happen)

Getting the length right is super easy if you create your file on the servers disk before sending.

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize("path and file name of csv to send"));
```

At the end of the day though, this is NOT an exact science and while you can do many things to try and force a browser to download your file, if the user has configured their browser to do something completely different then that's what will happen no matter what steps you take.

If your looking to add mime types to your apache config to support scenarios like this, then the Apache 'AddType' keyword is the one you need to look up:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html

If your going to use AddType, you need to make sure that you also have 'mod_mime' installed on your Apache server, generally though this is one of the defaults so should be there by default.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are not using the correct content-type header, should be:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
```